# Limit the number of containers started at once in a kubernetes chron job

Tags: kubernetes

I have a need that does not quite fit Argos or Airflow in that I would like to combine many containers into a pod and limit the number of containers started at once. The task is to kick off aggregation scripts (scrapy/crawlers, API calls;etc.). These scripts feed a separate system using a replica set to process the pulled data. I need to limit the number of containers running at once as there will likely be many running in the future. This isn't quite the use case for a DAG. These scripts have 1 task and I feel that combining 250 aggregators (or a divided amount) in a DAG with concurrency limits is a bit overkill for my task. I cannot seem to find the answer through a Google query. Is there a way to limit the number of containers executing at once? Each container runs a command to kick off the aggregator and terminates once the script finishes.

Comment: AFAIK, putting many containers inside one pod is not suggested, and there is no direct way of controlling those containers. I have no idea of how Airflow works, but maybe you can try putting all scripts inside one container and use a control script to select which scripts should be run.

Comment: Why do you want all containers in one pod? So they can address each other via localhost?

Comment: @Serge was originally planning on having chunks of aggergators in several pods to limit how many kicked off at once. more of a resource use thing. decided to go with airflow. somewhat heavy but it can work. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

No, there is no way to tell Kubernetes to manage the number of *containers* running in a Pod. This is purely up to the user when they define their Deployments/Daemonsets/Jobs etc.

Taken from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/):

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.

You can, however, manage batch workloads through Kubernetes Job resources which I will link [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/).

Jobs can specify the amount of parallelism at *Pod* granularity.

All this is to say that you would have to implement your workload as containers into separated Pods as is required by your use case. These Pods could talk to each other through ClusterIP Services. You can also keep tightly-coupled containers in the same Pod where they can talk over `localhost`.